# Show that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geqslant ab + bc + ca$ for all positive integers a, b, c

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

How would you show that the following inequality holds? Could you please write your reasoning by solving this problem too?

$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$  for all positive integers a, b, c

**I have tried:**

$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - ab + ab \ge bc + ca $

$(a^2 -2ab + b^2) + c^2 + ab \ge bc + ca $

$(a-b)^2 + c^2 + ab - bc - ca \ge 0 $

$(a-b)^2 + c(c - a) - b (c - a) \ge 0 $

$(a-b)^2 + (c - a)(c - b) \ge 0 $

Well, $(a-b)^2$ is positive. But how do we know if $(c-a)(c-b)$ is positive as well?

PS: The problem is from the book "How to think like a mathematician" by Kevin Housten.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$.

**Remark:** Using the above hint, you can show that the desired inequality holds for *all real numbers* $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Answer (score 5):

Actually your reasoning solves the question!

Note that, without loss of generality, you may order the numbers $a, b, c$ so that c is the greatest of them: $c \geq a , c\geq b$ You can do this because the inequality is symmetric in the variables $a, b, c$; i.e, if this wasn't true, have the greatest of the numbers and $c$ change places. Therefore your last term $(c-a)(c-b)$ IS positive.

"Without loss of generality" is an important part of thinking like a mathematician :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$0\leq (a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$$

Comment: Sorry could you explain why this solves the problem? I'm sure it must be something silly, but I don't see why this shows that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + ac + bc$

Comment: This shows that even a half of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is greater than $ab+ac+bc$.